# Using Lucid outside of AdonisJS controller

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm building a project with AdonisJS, and I want to build it as a modular, two-part application: The AdonisJS server runs a control panel, and a custom script outside that server runs an IRC bot. I've been trying to load Lucid into the second script so that I can interface with my database, but it only ever returns an empty object, `{}`. Some things to note:

- I've made sure my database is populated.
- I've tested code in my controllers that works and fetches results as expected.
- The secondary script boots up all the same parts of Adonis as server.js, sans the actual HTTP server.
- I have tried attaching this script to an HTTP server but it made no difference.
- I have also tried creating raw QueryBuilder objects with the same results.

Here's the least amount of code I can put together as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')
const bootstrap = require('./bootstrap/bot')

bootstrap(() =>
{
    const AppConfig = use('AppConfig')
    const Settings = use('App/Model/Settings')

    const get_settings = function * () {
        yield Settings.all()
    }

    console.log(get_settings())
})
```

`console.log()` prints `{}`, even though the same code called within a controller prints all entries from the settings table. `bootstrap/bot.js` is almost an exact replica of `bootstrap/http.js`. The only difference is that it doesn't start an HTTP server.

I've scoured the source code looking for things that might happen between starting the server and running controller code to see if there's something critical I'm missing, but I'm lost.

Does anyone know how I can use my Lucid models outside the confines of AdonisJS controllers?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your function is a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and you can only call a generator with the `yield` keyword.

So your `console.log()` should looks like `console.log(yield get_settings())`.

You may use the package [co](https://github.com/tj/co) to create the root generator function.

```
bootstrap(co(function * () {
  // ...
}))
```